# Firebase get class object from DataSnapshot with child arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have json object in my database:

```
{
 "title": "Blah blah"
 "children": [
  {...}, {...}
 ]
}
```

My android object looks like this:

```
public class MyObject {
  public String title;
  public ArrayList<ChildObject> children;
}
```

and all I want to do is:

```
MyObject object = dataSnapshot.getValue(MyObject.class);
```

And if title gets filled with right value, childs list will always be empty. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: I use the library with listeners and callback `onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) ...`

Comment: Try with `public List<Object> children;` My guess is that `Firebase` doesn't know what `ChildObject` is.